# Does Go have built-in package to create DNS-server?

Tags: go, dns

I don't know much about building DNS servers, but still.. Does Go have built-in packages to create DNS-server?

Comment: I don't know / don't think so...  Maybe, https://github.com/miekg/dns

Comment: https://godoc.org/?q=dns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the search on the language reference doesn't find something, I'd agree that there is no dns in the standard library [(Search on golang reference)](https://golang.org/search?q=dns).
Though I've already seen libraries on github.